# How do I subset a vector using a list of index of variable lengths

Tags: r, indexing, aggregate-functions

I am trying to determine an efficient way to gather the means and standard deviations of subsections of a variables in a dataframe based on a list of lengths of the sections within the variable. This is a small example of the type of data I have.

```
X1 <- c(1, 2.5, 3, .5, 1, 1.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 6, 8, 8, 6, 3, 4)
X2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
df <- c(X1, X2)
X3 <- list(3, 5, 4, 3)
```

I will note that the data I have are the result of preprocessing of a large data set of continuous time data that I inherited and the list (X3) represents the length of each sequence of X2.  Unfortunately, I need a mean and SD of each section of the vector. I tried using the `aggregate()` function

```
aggregate(X1, by = list(X2), FUN = mean)
```

but this code aggregates all of the "0" and "1" values together into two values.  I need 4 values.

I can't quite figure out how capture some function of each unique sequence of X2 without doing it locally by creating a factor for each separate sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I assume that you want to create a data frame with two columns, `X1` and `X2`. Here is how to create the data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(X1, X2)
df
#     X1 X2
# 1  1.0  0
# 2  2.5  0
# 3  3.0  0
# 4  0.5  1
# 5  1.0  1
# 6  1.5  1
# 7  3.0  1
# 8  3.5  1
# 9  4.0  0
# 10 6.0  0
# 11 8.0  0
# 12 8.0  0
# 13 6.0  1
# 14 3.0  1
# 15 4.0  1
```

We can then use the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package to calculate the mean and standard deviation of each group. The key is to use the `rleid` function to create the `ID` of each group. After that, we can summarize the data. `df2` is the final output. `X3` is actually not needed as long as you have the `X2` column in your data frame.

```
# Load the package
library(data.table)

# Convert df to a data.table
setDT(df)

# Perform rhe analysis
df2 <- df[, ID := rleid(X2)][, .(MEAN = mean(X1), SD = sd(X1)), by = ID]

df2[]
#    ID     MEAN       SD
# 1:  1 2.166667 1.040833
# 2:  2 1.900000 1.294218
# 3:  3 6.500000 1.914854
# 4:  4 4.333333 1.527525
```

Comment: Yes, I meant to describe X1 and X2 in a df and this code works perfectly.  I was unaware of the rleid function in data.table().  Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create grouping variable by comparing the adjacent elements and get the cumulative sum

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(X1, X2) %>% 
      group_by(ID = cumsum(X2 != lag(X2, default = X1[1]))) %>% 
      summarise(MEAN = mean(X1), SD = sd(X1))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#     ID  MEAN    SD
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  2.17  1.04
#2     2  1.90  1.29
#3     3  6.50  1.91
#4     4  4.33  1.53
```

---

Or if we have the number of elements in 'X3', create the grouping variable with `rep` and use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(X1 ~cbind(ID = rep(seq_along(X3),
     unlist(X3))), FUN = function(x) c(MEAN = mean(x), SD = sd(x))))
#  ID  X1.MEAN    X1.SD
#1  1 2.166667 1.040833
#2  2 1.900000 1.294218
#3  3 6.500000 1.914854
#4  4 4.333333 1.527525
```